# Playing part of a youtube video in mobile app

Tags: ios, mobile, youtube, youtube-api

We have a video platform on the web, which contains a lot of video files that we own, but also a fair amount of youtube videos. Those youtube embeds are actually small bits of youtube videos. We use the amazing Player API to specify the in/out time coordinates when played on a desktop browser.

The thing is, we are developping an App now, and we were not really sure if there is a way to port this behavior to mobile applications (Android/iOS). Is there ?

If we play the video using the native iOS player for example, will we be able to seek to a specified time immidiately ? I know we can make it stop when we want, but is it possible to specify a start time ?

Thanks you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use a [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can set it's `initialPlaybackTime` property before playing the content...

Comment: Great thanks, and would it work in progressive download ? Because by playing the youtube video file in the iOS Player, I guess it is handled as progressive download and not "real" streaming. Basically, you are saying that I could make the video load and play at i.e. 22m03s, without having to wait for it to download the data before this specific time ? Thanks again !

Comment: According to the docs, yes it should support only downloading from the desired start time. It'll probably download the file header first and then skip to the time you specify...

Comment: That's what I was thinking yeah, thank you very much for your insight on this, I will pass this on to the developers, and accept the answer if it works. Any other insight is still very welcome :)

Comment: It does work ! But actually the library I use to get the desired stream works 1 time out of 5, so it's not really reliable, and moreover it starts at a keyframe, so the initialPlaybackTime is not precise enough for me... Really hope the roll out their API for iOS soon... Thanks anyway !